# Checkbox check all in dynamic element

Tags: jquery

How can i make that checkbox to check all boxes in current result element ?
because atm on click this is check all boxes in all result elements

```
//dynamic row
var filter_row = 0;
function addFilterRow() {
  html = '<tr id="filter-row">';
  html += '  <td class="text-left">';
  html += '  <select class="company" name="company[]" class="form-control">';
  html += '  {% for company in damask_company %}';
  html += '  <option name="{{ company.filter_group_id }}" value="{{ company.filter_group_id }}">{{ company.name }}</option>';
  html += '  {% endfor %}';
  html += '  </select>';
  html += '</td>';
// Ajax return here 
  html += '<td class="text-left" id="result"></td>';

  html += '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(html);

  filter_row++;
}

$(document).on('change', 'select.company', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $result = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.result');
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = "index.php?route=catalog/product/getCat&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_group_id=" + id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {

   // checkbox to check all
      $result.append($('<p class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox" class="checkAll"> Select All</p>'));

        $result.append(data);
      }
    });
});
```

The way i fire check all

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkAll', function(){
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `change` event listener with `is(":checked")` like below.

Edit:

For single row you can use `closest` and find checkbox inside that `tr`.

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkAll', function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: somehow this do not work still same
if i click on check all in filter-row 1 its select and everything in  filter-row 2,3,4,5,6 if they exist

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the wrapper and find your checkboxes inside the wrapper

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkAll', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find(":checkbox").prop('checked',true);
});
```

This should select all checkboxes inside the `tr` the `selectAll` checkbox is located

Comment: yes i didnt even think about that ..
you are start ;)